# How to place the vertical line inbetween on cell

Tags: iphone

How to place the vertical line inbetween on cell

Comment: Improve your **accept** rate. It is just 25%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this link
http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=153

**Note:** I have copied code from the whole link and pasted it here, just to make sure answer remains useful even in case if the link goes down in future:

> UITableView is probably the most used view on the iPhone. It’s
>   flexible and the UI is ideally suited to use on the iPhone. There are
>   lots of examples on how to add multiple items to a UITableViewCell.
>   However, I needed to present some data in a more traditional
>   spreadsheet style grid. The results worked well and enabled me to pack
>   a lot of information on the screen that was very hard to follow
>   without the vertical grid. I’ll show a very simplified version here
>   you can use to add vertical lines to your UITableView.
>
> First we need to create a subclass of UITableViewCell. This is so we
>   can override drawrect and draw our lines and to add an array to hold a
>   list of positions where we’ll draw the lines.

```
@interface MyTableCell : UITableViewCell {
    NSMutableArray *columns;
}
- (void)addColumn:(CGFloat)position;
@end
```

> In this simplified example we’ll leave the positioning of the actual
>   text in the cells in the UITableViewController and place it manually
>   (full source code is attached at the end). We’re just providing a
>   mechanism for drawing vertical lines to make a grid. Column locations
>   are added by calling addColumn:

```
- (void)addColumn:(CGFloat)position {
    [columns addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:position]];
}
```

> Now lets override drawRect. In it we grab the current graphics context
>   and set the line color and width. Then we iterate over our columns
>   array drawing a line from the top of the cell row to the bottom at
>   each position stored in the array.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Use the same color and width as the default cell separator for now
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.25);

    for (int i = 0; i &lt; [columns count]; i++) {
        CGFloat f = [((NSNumber*) [columns objectAtIndex:i]) floatValue];
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, f, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, f, self.bounds.size.height);
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    [super drawRect:rect];
}
To add columns to the view just call

[cell addColumn:50];
when you’re building each cell.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyIdentifier %i", indexPath.row];

    MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[MyTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];

        UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 30.0,
                                                           tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease];
        [cell addColumn:50];
        label.tag = LABEL_TAG;
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label]; 

        label =  [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0, 0, 30.0,
                                                            tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease];
        [cell addColumn:120];
        label.tag = VALUE_TAG;
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        // add some silly value
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row * 4];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a bit of context in your answer, in case the link goes down. It also makes your answer look less spammy.

Comment: @Blowski: Great Comment..!! I have edited Aman's answer and added the code from the link.

Answer (score 0):

Give Left/Right border to each cell.

you will get vertical line in between cell

All the Best